@media inside ::before,::after pseudo element
Media queries can be used inside selectors, but they seem to be ignored inside pseudo elements in plain css.
Example:


  div.container {
    color: red;
    &::before {
      display: inline-block;
      content: "shouldn't display.";
      
      @media screen and (min-width: 1px) {
        content: "should display?";
      }
      
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 1px) {
      &::before {
        content: "displays?";
      }
    }
  }
  
div.no-nest::before {
  content: "shouldn't display.";

  @media screen and (min-width: 1px) {
    content: "should display";
  }
}

div.no-pseudo {
  
  span.hide {
    @media screen and (min-width: 1px) {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
<div class="container">
  -- content here.
</div>

<div class="no-nest">
  -- content without nested css
</div>

<div class="no-pseudo">
  <span class="hide">shouldn't display</span>
  <span class="show">should display</span>
  -- content without pseudo
</div>



https://jsfiddle.net/jwe6kcda/1/
Is this correct? Does the spec say this is not possible? This usually works in SCSS and I'm surprised this didn't carry over when the specification for nested css was made, specially since it works for any .selector.

"Does the spec say..." Here's the spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-nesting-1/

was looking into the @media spec, but this has an answer.

The spec explicitly tells that:

The nesting selector cannot represent pseudo-elements (identical to the behavior of the :is() pseudo-class).

-- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-nesting-1/#nest-selector
I.e. the same way like you cannot target ::before with `:is():
*:is(::before){ /* never matches anything */ } 
*:has(::before){ /* neither this */ } 

the same way you cannot refer to ::before with &
*::before { & { /* never matches */ } }

Spec refers to discussion mentioning it might be relaxed in the future, but will demand substantial changes in related mechanisms. Not sure if it is likely to happen.

https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/7433
https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/9492


Not 100% sure if nesting with & and its spec is equivalent to nested @media rules (or other @ rules for that matter). Posted another answer based on that and other specs.

Well I always thought that nested @media block effectively constitutes "implied" & { ... } block within, in a similar way like the & is (nowadays) optional yet inherently present in all nested rules. But on the seconds though, not sure about that.

That's sorta what I understood from reading the specs.

The spec for css nesting says that "In addition to nested style rules, this specification allows nested group rules inside of style rules: any at-rule whose body contains style rules can be nested inside of a style rule as well."
Then here, the definition of "style rule" states: "A style rule is a qualified rule that associates a selector list with a list of property declarations".
Selector List: "A list of simple/compound/complex selectors is a comma-separated list of simple, compound, or complex selectors."
Which has an issue, noted in the spec "Pseudo-elements aren’t handled here, and should be."
So yeah, the way I see it, common sense says it should work, but there's an issue with the spec itself.
thanks to @heretic-monkey for the link to the spec.
